# Is $\langle X,Y\rangle / m_{a} \langle X,Y\rangle$ a one-dimensional $K$ -vector space?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

This is motivated by one of my previous posts, [$ \mathfrak{m}_{a}=\left\langle X-a^{2}, Y-a^{3}\right\rangle $ is maximal ideal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4000447). In short,

> Let $K$ be a field, and let $R$ be the ring $K[X, Y] /\left\langle X^{3}-Y^{2}\right\rangle$. For any element $a$ of $K \setminus \{0\},$ show that the ideal $\mathfrak{m}_{a}=\left\langle X-a^{2}, Y-a^{3}\right\rangle$ makes $I / m_{a} I$ into a one-dimensional $K$ -vector space, where $I$ is the ideal of $R$ generated by $X$ and $Y$.

To do this (I know this holds, but not the solution), I want to show that there is a unit of $R$ (i.e. element of $K$) inside $\left\langle X-a^{2}, Y-a^{3}\right\rangle$. I tried this using $X^3 - Y^2 = 0$. That is, $(X-a^2 + a^2)^3 - (Y-a^3 + a^3)^2 = 0$, and then I expanded this out. The result is a 'polynomial' in the variables $X-a^2, Y-a^3$. So I just ended up showing $0 \in \left\langle X-a^{2}, Y-a^{3}\right\rangle$, which is obvious anyway (but I can't help but think this step will be useful somewhere). I tried messing with this expression to induce a unit inside $\left\langle X-a^{2}, Y-a^{3}\right\rangle$, but I've had no luck. What are the possible next steps? Is what I did even necessary?

Edit: It seems as though trying to show that there is a unit inside $\left\langle X-a^{2}, Y-a^{3}\right\rangle$ is not a good approach (the claim is not true). Now I'm even more lost. Does anyone know how to proceed?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question, but maximal ideals are definitionally proper, so if its maximal, it certainly won't contain $1$.

Comment: If $1\in \left\langle X-a^2, Y-a^3\right\rangle$, then the ideat is all of $R$ and the quotient would be the trivial group.

Comment: @jMdA  Yes, that's what I want to happen. Based on the comments, it seems as though that condition is not necessary to solve the problem. I will edit the question.

Comment: @Countable You are absolutely right! I feel bad for missing this. I have edited the question.

Comment: your question is not clear at all. You say that $I$ is an ideal of $R$, but your generators are $X$ and $Y$ ? Moreover, $m_a$ is a ideal of $K[X]$. How do you define $m_aI$ if $I$ is an ideal of $R$?

Comment: @GreginGre Hi, that's the way the problem was presented. Here, $R$ is defined to be the ring $K[X, Y] /\left\langle X^{3}-Y^{2}\right\rangle$. $\mathfrak{m}_a$ is the ideal generated by $X-a^2, Y-a^3$ in $R$. So it is an ideal of $R$, and not of $K[X]$. $I$ and $\mathfrak{m}_a$ are both ideals of $R$, so their product (an ideal product) is well-defined. Does this make sense?

Comment: sorry, i meant $K[X,Y]$. It still does not make sense, sorry. Instead of $X,Y$, you should work with $x,y$, the classes of $X,Y$ modulo $X^3-Y^2$

Comment: @reuns Oh, no worries! Thank you for the answer anyway, I did (+1) before it was deleted.

Comment: Sorry I was misreading the question. I think the point is that $(I,m_a)=(1)$ so $R/(Im_a)\cong R/I\times R/m_a$ and the image of $I$ is $0\times R/m_a\cong K.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I pointed out in my comment, if we want to be precise, we should say that $I=(x,y)$ and $\mathfrak{m}_a=(x-a^2,y-a^3)$, where $x,y$ are the classes of $X,Y$ modulo $X^3-Y^2$, since we work with ideals of $R$.

However, this does not really matter here. Let $I'=(X,Y),$ $\mathfrak{m}'_a=(X-a^2,Y-a^3)$.  I claim that both ideals $I'$ and $\mathfrak{m}'_a $ contain $X^2-Y^3$. This is clear for $I'$. Moreover, note that $\mathfrak{m}'_a$ is the set of polynomials such that $P(a^2,a^3)=0$, so $X^3-Y^2\in\mathfrak{m}'_a$.

That said, we get that $I=I'/(X^3-Y^2),\mathfrak{m}_aI=\mathfrak{m}'_aI' /(X^3-Y^2)$ and we have a canonical isomorphism $I/\mathfrak{m}_aI\simeq I'/\mathfrak{m}'_aI'$.

Hence, we can forget about the classes modulo $X^2-Y$ of $R$ and work with ideals of $K[X,Y]$ instead.

So to simplify notation, I will get rid of the $'$  in the arguments above.

Since $\mathfrak{m}_a=(X-a^2,Y-a^3)$ is the set of polynomials such that $P(a^2,a^3)=0$, any polynomial $P\in K[X,Y]$ may be written as $\alpha+ M$, where $\alpha\in K$ and $M\in\mathfrak{m}_\alpha$ (more precisely, $\alpha=P(a^2,a^3),$ and $M=P-P(a^2,a^3)$).

Taking into account that an element of $I=(X,Y)I$ has the form $XP+YQ,P,Q\in K[X,Y]$, we see that an element of $I/\mathfrak{m_a}I$ may be represented by a polynomial of the form $\alpha X+\beta Y$, where $\alpha,\beta \in K$.

Now, $\mathfrak{m}_a I$ contains $(Y-a^3)X-(X-a^2)Y=a^2(Y-aX)$. Since $a\neq 0,\mathfrak{m}_a I$ contains $Y-aX$. Thus, any element of   $I/\mathfrak{m_a}I$ may be represented by an element of the form $\gamma X$, where $\gamma\in K$. This proves that this $K$-vector space is spanned by the class of $X$, and has dimension $\leq 1$. To prove that this vector space is not zero, we should prove that $X$ does not lie in $\mathfrak{m}_a I$. But $\mathfrak{m}_a I\subset \mathfrak{m}_a$. Since the value of $X$ at $(a^2,a^3)$ is $a^2\neq 0$, we are done.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent proof! Yes, the notation that I was taught is indeed confusing... There are a lot of 'assumed' quotients lurking, and that makes my notation hard to read.